# Creating Folders in C# Project Using CMake

Tags: c#, cmake, project, solution

I've used `source_group` dozens of times with C++ Projects to organize my files, yet for C# Projects this does not seem to work:

```
set (FOO myfoo.cs)
set (BAR mybar.cs)
set (FILES  
  App.xaml
  App.xaml.cs
  MainWindow.xaml
  MainWindow.xaml.cs
)

set (PROPERTIES <property files here>)

add_executable(
  ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
  App.config
  ${FILES}
  ${FOO}
  ${BAR}
  ${PROPERTIES}
)

source_group(Models FILES ${FOO})
source_group(ViewModels FILES ${BAR})
```

Do folders not work for C# Projects via CMake? Or what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Forgot to mention, in my main CMakeLists.txt file I already have:

```
if (WIN32)
    SET_PROPERTY(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
endif (WIN32)
```

I then call add_subdirectory where the above CMakeLists.txt is. This setup seems to work okay for my other C++ project that is added in the same way.

Comment: You example code seems to be missing the [`USE_FOLDERS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/USE_FOLDERS.html) global property activation.

Comment: Just updated the question. I'm actually already including that in my top level CMakeLists.txt. That same CMakeLists is adding this C# subdirectory, as well as another C++ directory in which source_group folders are working fine in. Honestly it seems like this isn't supported in C# projects. Having a hard time confirming that, however. Have you seen it done?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `VS_CSHARP_Link` property to set how a file is viewed in a C# project. (Don't ask for documentation; I can't find any. I learned about this setting by perusing the source code. Looks like it first appeared in version 3.18.)

For example, after adding `${SOME_ROOT_DIR}/some/path/to/someFile.cs` to your project's sources, control how it's organized with:

```
    set_source_files_properties("${SOME_ROOT_DIR}/some/path/to/someFile.cs"
        PROPERTIES VS_CSHARP_Link "My own folder\someFile.cs")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in C# Projects, source_group is not honored. However, folders are still possible simply by giving it a directory structure in the list, like so:

```
set(MODELS
    Models/CompileOptionsModel.cs
)

set(VIEWMODELS
    ViewModels/CompileOptionsViewModel.cs
)

set(PROPERTIES
 ...
)

set(Files
 ...
)

add_executable(
    ${APPNAME}
    App.config
    ${MODELS}
    ${VIEWMODELS}
    ${FILES}
    ${PROPERTIES}
)
```

This will result in folders Models and ViewModels appearing.